# NETTY ISSUE Client 1024 byte message

Tags: java, netty

i wanted to report this error directly, but did not find any possibility yet from main page netty.io

I have noticed an error while sending data to channel. It happens not always, in 10-20% of cases, but it happens.
Following,

1. as example, if I get first connection with message of 1024 byte data, everything is fine till now, than I create socket to forwarded address doing it with HexDumpProxyInboundHandler
2. and here is fine everything, except one thing, I have created an listener on forwarded address with traffic logging, where i get the messages which were sent by Netty. I would expect the data of 1024 bytes on it, but it happens not always, not also in 100% of cases.
   sometimes...
3. exactly sometimes the nightmare begins here, 
   if i get on same channel next message after 1024 bytes message, the data gets written in following possible forms:

3.1 either the first message and second message are merged and the data that i get on my port listener is correct, 1024 + 72(as example) and in correct byte order too (but in merged form, what is already not correct for me)

3.2 or the first message and second message are merged too, but with one little difference, with different order, 72(as example) + 1024 bytes, even if data was correctly received by server socket, and in correct order.. the sending order was incorrect also.

3.3 or finally the first message of 1024 gets send as is following by second message which gets send as is too, so everything is fine here too, and that is the correct and expected behavior..

Also, the error happens not always, but it happens, and always, if it happens, it happens only if by first connection the first message was 1024 byte long and the second message was sent immediately after first message without the received data before.

Now the question to community, is that possible to switch off such strange buffering behavior in Netty? So that all messages received on server socket are sent exactly in same way to the client socket channel without merging the data.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

This "strange" behavior has nothing todo with netty. Its up to the network layer how much bytes get transfered at once, so its really expected to see this. if you need to have all 1024 bytes you will need t buffer them until you receive enough.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after long night I have finally solved my problem. It seems, the Netty project is still buggy in this way and will accept incoming messages for sending in the wrong order.
So, what I do, I fill the buffer with incoming messages until the remote connection by client gets opened, so I send than the full correct buffer instead to let things do by Netty.